# How do i prove there exists a function $F(n+1)=f_n(F(1),...,F(n))$?

Tags: set-theory, induction

Let $X$ be a set and $f_n:X^n \rightarrow X$ be a function for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $c\in X$.

How do i prove that there exists $F:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ such that $F(n+1)=f_n(F(1),...,F(n))$ and $F(1)=c$?

Plus, is this $F$ unique?

Comment: This is a definition by recursion. Look up the recursion theorem on wikipedia or a set theory textbook for a more form. For the general recursion theorem, well-foundedness is the key idea. It is good to at least see the justification for definition by recursion at least once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The quick brute-force method would be to use Zorn's lemma.

Consider the set of all functions $A\to X$ where $A$ is an initial sequence of $\mathbb N$ and the function satisfies your equation. Order the functions by set inclusion. Zorn's lemma says there is a maximal element. The *domain* of this maximal element cannot have a largest element, because then you would easily construct a function that went one higher. Therefore the domain must be $\mathbb N$ itself, and the maximal element is your $F$.

(It can be done without Zorn or choice, but there will be more thinking involved then).

For uniqueness, suppose there are $F$ and $G$ that both satisfy your equation. Prove by (long) induction on $n$ that $F(n)=G(n)$ for all $n$, and therefore $F=G$.

Comment: What do you mean "an initial sequence of $\mathbb{N}$?"

Comment: what's $A$ and how is it nonempty?

Comment: I mean, how is the set of all functions $A\rightarrow X$ nonempty?

Comment: An initial sequence is (for this purpose) a subset $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ such that if $x\in A$ and $y<x$ then $y\in A$. The set of such functions is nonempty because the empty function (where $A=\varnothing$) is certainly there. And so is the function $\{1\mapsto c\}$ with $A=\{1\}$.

Comment: @William: In this case, the upper bound of any chain is the union of the functions in the chain. One can prove that this union is a function, that its domain is an initial segment (as I've defined it above), and that it satisfies the recursion equation. Note that I do not require initial segments to be finite.

Comment: @William: That argument assumes that you _already_ know there's an infinite chain to take the union of in the first place.